# Paper Soccer Java

Tags: java, algorithm, bots

I wanna implement in Java a bot that plays [paper soccer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_Soccer), but I don't know how to start.

What kind of algorithm do I need to choose for lowest complexity? Any ideas about how I can do it?

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow. It will be much easier for us to help you with your question if you would describe [what you have already tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 3):

Start with learning how similar algorithms are written.

chess http://www.sluijten.com/winglet/

An Introduction to Game Tree Algorithms

http://www.hamedahmadi.com/gametree/

Answer (score 0):

try [minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), but it won't be so easy.

Comment: minimax, even with alpha beta pruning, killer heuristic etc, I don't think will be powerful enough due to the span of the game and there being no good trivial board evaluation algorithm. But it'll work if you can come up with a good fast board evaluation algorithm or if you can search really deep

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm is to test each of the 8 directions for validity and then choose one of them randomly. You probably want to favour directions that move closer to the opponents goal.
You could assign 60% probability equally over all choices, and then assign 20% extra to the best choice and 10% extra to each of the second and third best choice. If only 2 choices are available assign a 75/25% chance. When there is only one available choice, then there is no need for randomness.

**Edit:**

Example 1: 
Starting position, goal at top of screen, percent chance for each move:

```
17.5 27.5 17.5
 7.5       7.5
 7.5  7.5  7.5
```

Example 2:

So, how to rank the moves from best to worst? I would use the distance from the goal in each direction and add it if you move towards the goal and subtract if you move away. So if the goal is 7 squares up and 3 squares to the left then the score for each direction would be:

```
10  7   4
 3     -3
-4 -7 -10
```

Let's say there are 5 possible moves in the above situation and that the illegal moves happen to be up, up-right and down-right, then percent chance for each move would be (the illegal moves have been assigned 0 chance):

```
32  0  0
22    22
12 12  0
```

Comment: Please, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I've added some examples.